# terraform init with module sources giving an error for sub-directories

Tags: git, terraform

I am trying to use terraform with modules sources using git and ssh.
I am not sure how to call the sub-directories, the documentation (https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#local-file-paths)
says to use // for sub-directories

But i am getting an error when i use the same. Has anyone tried it, pls help

folder-structure

```
  --terraform-module
    --main.tf
    --modules 
       --sql
          --main.tf
```

terraform init

```
- module.sql
  Updating source "git::ssh://git@gitlab.xxxxx.com/folder1/terraform-module.git//modules/sql"
Error loading modules: subdir "modules/sql" not found
```

code:

```
module "sql" {
  source                  = "git::ssh://git@gitlab.xxx.com/folder1/terraform-module.git//modules/sql"
```

Comment: Did you intend to have a double slash `//` in your path?

Comment: You only need the `//` for Github/Bitbucket sourcing, not for generic Git repos that you are using with Gitlab. See https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#generic-git-repository

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Thanks a ton. 
git::ssh://git@gitlab.xxx.com/folder1/terraform-module.git?ref=dev//modules/sql